# NEO4j: Help manipulating list in RETURN

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am confused about how collect works when I unwind it.

I am collecting node properties from various optional matches and ending up with list that has duplicates:

```
list=[
  [ID: 1, value: 0],
  [ID: 1, value: 4],
  [ID: 1, value: 90],
  [ID: 2, value: 40],
  [ID: 2, value: 0],
  ...,
]
```

I can't collect just the nodes - it has to be a list because the values are computed as I collect them.

```
UNWIND list AS node
WITH distinct node
```

Unwind above does not bring it down to just one row for ID: 1, which I understand because at this point the list items are different and not related to the ID: 1 node anymore.

I'd like to only keep the row with the highest value for each ID. Can this be done on the RETURN?
   Expected result: `[[ID: 1, value: 90], [ID: 2, value: 40]]`

I looked at apoc list and map functions but nothing seems to address this. Is there a reduce or coalesce type thing that would work?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I presume that your lists contain maps like `{ID: 1, value: 0}`, not illegal constructs like `[ID: 1, value: 0]`.*

You can use the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/) `MAX`:

```
UNWIND list AS node
RETURN {ID: node.ID, value: MAX(node.value)};
```

Or, if you want the result to be a list of maps:

```
UNWIND list AS AS node
WITH {ID: node.ID, value: MAX(node.value)} AS item
RETURN COLLECT(item);
```

Comment: Yes, sorry - my list is a map {}.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will have to play with it a little to understand better. The WITH {ID: node.ID, value: MAX(node.value)} AS item creates a new concatenated list with just what I want, but I'm still not understanding the need to collect item afterwards. I wish this came to me more intuitively. Thanks!

Comment: Your question's "expected result" is a list of maps. That is why I showed how to produce that.